# How to Send A Token to an Smart Contract Alongside a Datum?

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, token, datum, smart-contract

I asked another question ([How to Make Sure A Contract Is Signed By a Certain Party?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/how-to-make-sure-a-contract-is-signed-by-a-certain-party/8340?noredirect=1#comment4361_8340)) and got the answer I expected.

It raised the secondary Question of how to send a token with a datum to a smart contract to enable custom permissions via the validator.